# AUTO_INCREMENT в базе

Tags: phpmyadmin

Вопрос такой, можно ли как-то продолжать нумерацию после удаления всех к примеру некоторых новостей.
Чтобы не было больших пробелов.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можно. Но сама перенумерация автоинкремента не имеет смысла.

Comment: Если вы хотите заполнить интервалы, то придется это делать "вручную": то есть находить первый пропущенный id и вставлять новость с таким id, ошибку это не вызовет. Автоматического заполнения в SQL не предусмотрено. А главный вопрос зачем это нужно?

Comment: Вы боитесь, что закончатся айдишники? Вы знаете какой последний номер у большого типа в БД? int - 4294967295. bigint - 2 в 64 степени. Долго будете добираться) И даже если вдруг доберётесь, то проблему нехватки решают по-другому